# Transmission not responsive - Dodge Durango 2001 slt 4.7

Tags: transmission, dodge

My truck was in a salt water flood when hurricane Sandy hit New Jersey. Since then, the motor was replaced, ECM computer, shocks, ball joints, hubs, rear, front calipers, power steering pump, A/C compressor, map sensor, battery along with other minor parts. But recently my automatic transmission has become non-responsive. I could not get any gear to work. Right before this happened I started losing response as I was driving and rolled to a stop. I shut my truck off and restarted it and it worked fine until I stopped at a red light. Then I lost all response again. So after sitting for a couple of days with dry weather I tried to put it in drive and the transmission was responsive. So I tried every gear and it was okay. I was even able to power brake and smoke the tires at a standstill. I believe it must be electrical a sensor or relay or something. What do you think?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about what the transmission does when it is not responsive? Does the engine rev, but it does not appear to catch the gear? Does the vehicle stall?

Comment: The engine revs and does not stall..it's like the trans does not exist.but like I said today I checked it again and it went into gear but I did not drive it because I was worried about getting stuck on the road again.but I was able to power brake it and smoke the tire in my parking spot.so I assume the trans is strong .

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid levels? Can you see any obvious signs of leakage under the vehicle?

Comment: No leaks,fluid level is good.also the fluid has no indication of burning.the fluid color is normal and ther was no metal shavings .i am going by the dip stick readings .

Comment: Is there a nuet

Comment: Is there a nuetrul relay or some type of sensor that could be malfunctioning due to the salt water corrosion over time

Comment: Is it a 4x4? If it is, does your transfer case shift from 4x2, 4x4L etc via a floor mounted lever or a pushbutton?

Comment: I would bet the issue is the electronic connection to the transmission has corroded. If you take the connector off and clean everything out, it may start working again.

Comment: @Msgambati007  Did you resolve this issue?  Were any of the comments useful to you?  I hope so.  If it's resolved could you answer your question with what you did.  We don't like to see unresolved issues and hope you were able to resolve yours.  Answering your question will make this site more valuable to others in the future.  Thanks and I hope the problem has been solved.  Happy New Year!